# Logstash unable to create new field as expected from two field one is long type other is string type

Tags: logstash

I am trying to join two field in logstash during filter, data is fetched from database, one field type is long type (issue_num) and other is string type(project_key) .

I am using following filter.

```
filter {
  mutate {
   add_field => { "IssueLink" => "%{project_key}-%{issue_num}" }
  }
}
```

"project_key":"DOCS"
"issue_num":667

*Actual Output*
**"IssueLink":"DOCS-0.667E3"**

*Expected Output* **"IssueLink":"DOCS-667"**

why the output is not expected ? What's the problem here ?

Comment: What version of logstash are you running?

Comment: I am using - logstash 2.4.0